# Getting Error When Insert data in Ms access 2007 using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access-2007

Here is My code . when ever i enter data in TextBox3 and TextBox4 without special characters its fine and when i enter data which contain special characters such as ",.;:#".
please give me solution thank you

```
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

   OleDbConnection mycon = new OleDbConnection();

   mycon.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\AGENTJ.AGENTJ-PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\mfaridalam\App_Data\mfaridalam1.accdb";

   cmd = mycon.CreateCommand();

   mycon.Open();
   cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Image] ([Image],[Sort],[Created],[Albumid],[Description],[title])VALUES('" + filename + "','" + ips + "','" + dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "','" + newtable + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "')";


    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Take a look at how to use [CommandParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Using a [parameterized query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) will help avoid these types of quoting errors, and will also protect the application from *SQL injection* attacks and other strange behaviours. They are slightly less compact to code, but they are well worth the effort.